# Making script to create database skeleton for SQL Server 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, installation, setup-project

I'm making Visual Studio setup for my project.

I want it automatically create empty database inside some SQL Server 2008 (Express)

1. Is there some tool / way to automatic generate such script of my database (sadly my database structure isn't stable yet)
2. How can I add it to installation process ? I know that I can run programs and scripts during installation but how can I specify SQL Server for my script ?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSMS, Right-Click on database -> Tasks... -> Generate Scripts....

Suggest you also look at using the [Database GDR R2 projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en) (if using VS 2008) or the built-in database project if using VS 2010.